# why I'm getting this error and how to resolve this error?

Tags: owasp

root@KaliP:~# zaproxy
./zap.sh: line 48: [: 9-Debian: integer expression expected
Exiting: ZAP requires a minimum of Java 7 to run, found 9-Debian

Comment: So it says **ZAP requires a minimum of Java 7 to run** and then you proceed to ask how to resolve the issue?

Comment: whatever is happing at that point in your `zap.sh:48`  the shell is expecting an exit code of 0 or 1.  It's not getting that.  Perhaps post your code?

Comment: @lacostenycoder here is my code on line 48                                                             if [ $JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION -ge 1 ] && [ $JAVA_MINOR_VERSION -ge 7 ]; then
  echo "Found Java version $JAVA_VERSION"
else
  echo "Exiting: ZAP requires a minimum of Java 7 to run, found $JAVA_VERSION"
  exit 1
fi

Comment: Make sure any Java version is installed, probably 7.  Also you should post your code in body of your question using code indentation.  Hard to read in a comment like this.